# font error with " myFont = createFont("Verdana", 48, true);" in game

Tags: fonts, processing

Running into an error "cannot find anything named "myFont". Using " myFont = createFont("Verdana", 48, true);" in a game program and not sure if I have a typo or a real error. Have proofread thru the program several times and not coming up with anything.
I'll feel really dumb if this is a typing error...
tried loading thru the tolbox, but that didnt seem to work either...
Have program and Class sections - will post both.

Cards:

```
class Cards
{
  int show = 0; // shows the back of the card
  PImage cardImage;

  int cardX = 0;
  int cardY = 0;
  int faceValue = 0;
  int myPoints = 0;

  // card back is 00 so there are '53' cards vs 52

  String[] cardName = {
    "00.png", "01.png", "02.png", "03.png", "04.png", "05.png", "06.png", "07.png", "08.png", "08.png", 
    "09.png", "10.png", "11.png", "12.png", "13.png", "14.png", "15.png", "16.png", "17.png", "18.png", 
    "19.png", "20.png", "21.png", "22.png", "23.png"     
  };

  Cards (int x, int y, int fv, int mp)
  {
    cardX = x;
    cardy = y;
    faceValue = fv;
    myPoints = mp;  //keeps track of the points J=11, Q=12, K=13
  }

  void display()
  {    
    cardImage= loadImage(cardName[show]); //Display loads the images.
    image(cardImage, cardX, cardY);
  }

  void setX(int newX)  //move the card from the deck to the center and 
  {
    cardX = newX;
    show = faceValue;
  }

  int getPoints()  //gets the points from the card values compare the left to the right.
  {
    return (myPoints);
  }
}
```

Program:

```
void setup()    
{
  background(0);
  int myY =75;
  int myX1 = 430;  //each pile has its own x value
  int myX2 = 50;
  size(600, 600);
  fill(255, 0, 0);
  myFont = createFont("Verdana", 48, true);
  for (int i = 0; i<20; i++)
  {
    y[i] = myY;
    fv[i] = i+1;
    points [i] = currentPoint;
    currentPoint ++;
    if (currentPoint > 10)  //since only doing 10 cards each side - total 20 change this
    {
      currentPoint=1;  //then resetting at one - counts  -10 and then starts over.
      //so the point value matchs the face value of the cards. ace =1, 2=2, etc j=11, q=12, k=13
    }

    if (i%2==0)    
    {
      x[i] = myX1;
      myY+=2;  //changes the pixels of the cards so they are not all on top of eachother
      // the cards will show slightlu fanned down and to the right with these functions
      myX1+=2;
      myX2+=2;
    }
    else
    {
      x[i] = myX2;
    }
  }

  shuffle(); // shuffle a couple of times
  shuffle();

  for (int i=0; i<20; i++)
  {
    myCard[i] = new Cards (x[i], y[i], fv[i], points[i]);
  }
}

void draw()
{
  background(0);
  textFont(myFont);
  text(leftPoint, 75, 50);
  text(rightPoint, 515, 50);
  rect(200, 400, 200, 100);
  for (int i=0; i<20; i++)
  {
    myCard[i].display();  //display cards on the screen
  }

  if (leftDeck>19)  //CHANGE means went throug all the cards
  {
    if (leftPoint > rightPoint)
    {
      text("Left Wins!", 250, 350);
    }
    else if (leftPoint<rightPoint)
    {
      text("Right Wins!", 250, 350);
    }
    else
    {
      text("you TIED!!!!", 250, 350);
    }
  }
}

void mouseClicked()
{
  if (mouseX<400 && mouseX>200 && mouseY<500 && mouseY>400)
  {
    myCard[leftDeck].setX(190);  //set x value for left card display
    myCard[rightDeck].setX(310); //sets x value for right card display
    if (myCard[leftDeck].getPoints()>myCard[rightDeck].getPoints())
    {
      leftPoint++;
    }
    else if (myCard[leftDeck].getPoints()<myCard[rightDeck].getPoints())
    {
      rightPoint++;
    }  
    leftDeck+=2;
    rightDeck+=2;
  }
}

void shuffle()
{
  int temp = 0;
  int tempPoint =0;
  int rand = 0;
  for (int i=0; i<20; i++)  //CHANGE to 52
  {
    rand = int(random(0, 20));  //showing 20 needs to be 52
    temp = fv[i];
    tempPoint = points[i];
    fv[i] = fv[rand];
    points[i] = points[rand];  //have to move the point value with the facevalue
    fv[rand] = temp;
    points[rand] = tempPoint;
  }
}
```

Comment: If you are going to downgrade the question, program or information - you could at least say why. I am new at all this and on the edge of my experience, otw I wouldn't ask.

Comment: remember to tag your questions appropriately. You're not asking about fonts, you're actually asking about a Processing program. Also remember you're asking other human beings for help, so make sure your code's formatted at least sensibly (i.e. not with an ocean of whitespace)

Comment: as addendum: in the future, please only post relevant code. If you're getting an error about `myFont`, reduce your problem. I.e. copy your files to a new dir, open that in your favourite editor, and start deleting everything not related to your error, and then use that drastically reduced code in your question. Typically, while reducing, you discover the problem on your own and don't even need to ask on Stackoverflow anymore, so it's a good exercise (no matter how skilled a programmer you are, reducing is still step 2, right after step 1: "following the error directly")

Answer (score 0):

This seems fairly obvious: the error is telling you that `myFont` doesn't exist in the context you're calling it. Which makes sense: you never declared a variable by that name before initialising it. Somewhere at the same level of your `setup` and `draw` you need to issue a:

```
Font myFont;
```

so that when `setup()` runs, there is an actual variable called `myFont` that can hold the result of the `createFont` call.